# Popup issues in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I am working with loadrunner 12.53 using http/html protocol. My script contains a radio button, i am clicking on it and saving it and moving to the next page. This is the flow.

I am sending radio button value as 2, but in the response it is always taking as 0 value, which means it is not selecting either of the radio buttons, i have tried giving values of radio button instead of numberings but then also, in response, we are getting as 0, can anybody please suggest how to handle this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow!  To help other coders better assist you.  Please use periods "." when forming sentences.  Also a code example of what you have tried would be very helpful in getting the proper solution to the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you elect to use an HTTP virtual user, there is no end user interface to activate a button.  You are simply reproducing the data flows associated with the end user interface to the server.   When you write, "... which means it is not selecting either of the radio buttons..." this is very confusing.

If you are not receiving your expected response from the server, then consider there may be other items upstream from this particular request which have not been addressed well, either with unhandled dynamic data or not checking for expected results content (simply accepting HTTP 200 as success).  Either condition would result in the state of an application out of alignment with the request being sent....which in turn results in an unexpected response.